# Having a hard time with procedure not formatting the query entry correctly

Tags: sql, plsql

> Create a dynamic procedure that will change the contents of any column for any row in the AA_EMPLOYEE table using the employee id. i.e.

```
BEGIN 
dyn_aa_employee('emp_dob', '01-jan-18', 110); 
END;
```

> Will change the date of birth for employee ID 110

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_aa_employee
   (p_col VARCHAR2,
    p_dob IN aa_employee.emp_dob%TYPE,
    p_id NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE aa_employee 
      SET '|| p_col ||' = :ph_dob 
      WHERE EMP_NUM = :ph_id'
   USING p_dob, p_id;

BEGIN
    dyn_aa_employee('emp_dob', '01-jan-18', 110);   
END;
```

The top code has to work for the bottom code. The issue is it's changing the emp dob to 01-jan-0018, however I want it to change to exactly 01-jan-18.

My professor gave me a 0 for this assignment I'm just trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that aa_employee.emp_dob is of type date AND assuming that by '01-jan-18' you mean January 1st, 2018, either you do this:

```
BEGIN
    dyn_aa_employee('emp_dob', date '2018-01-01', 110);   
END;
```

or you could change your procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_aa_employee (
   p_col      VARCHAR2,
   p_dob   IN aa_employee.emp_dob%TYPE,
   p_id       NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'UPDATE aa_employee SET ' || p_col || ' = :ph_dob WHERE EMP_NUM = :ph_id'
      USING TO_DATE (p_dob, 'DD-MON-YY'), p_id;
END;
```

It would be interesting to see the actual assignment, though. It's a rather confused scenario overall and I don't see how it teaches you much except to identify several things you probably shouldn't do.

Comment: So i'm still getting the 0018 https://imgur.com/MAoXfMM either my professor gave me the wrong table or I'm asking the wrong question

Comment: Create a dynamic procedure that will change the contents of any column for any row in the AA_EMPLOYEE table using the employee id. i.e.

BEGIN
 dyn_aa_employee('emp_dob', '01-jan-18', 110); 
END;
Will change the date of birth for employee ID 110.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you didn't specify the date format you were passing. Therefore accepting whatever format the professor had setup. This is a bad plan, to be safe always specify your date format and don't depend on the default. Defaults can and are changed too often. This is a good lesson why you should always specify the actual date format you're using. Try the following to see the difference:

```
with ds as 
    (select '01-jan-18' dt_stg from dual)
select to_date(dt_stg), to_date(dt_stg, 'dd-mon-rr') from ds;
```

Secondly, seems the assignment was to create a procedure that could update any column. This procedure can update only a column having the same type as "aa_employee.emp_dob%TYPE",presumable a date, but it cannot update any other column type.  
Finally, if your trying to figure out what professor thinks you did wrong, then try something strange: ask your professor!